# OPEN POLICY AGENT: Unable to download bundles from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, bundle, opa, open-policy-agent

I have set s3 related information as in config.yaml.This get call also returned 200 ok response.

GET call: [https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/{bucket_name}/policy.tar.gz](https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/object/%7Bbucket_name%7D/policy.tar.gz)

But when download, it showing the error as below

{"level":"error","msg":"Bundle load failed: bundle read failed: archive read failed: gzip: invalid header","name":"aut
hz","plugin":"bundle","time":"2022-03-10T22:35:32+05:30"}

Can anyone help to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the URL from the AWS console, but will need to use the object URL for the bundle file, which should look something like this:

```
https://my-opa-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bundle.tar.gz
```

If you click the bundle file in the S3 console, you'll see the correct URL under "Object URL":

[image]